# How to set min and max value colormap 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following two graphs, I need the legend(color map) to start from same value, how is this possible to set. For instance in both graph it should be from 5600 till 6100. Thanks help is highly appreciated

```
data = np.genfromtxt("C:/data/time.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('CPU(%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Memory (%)')
ax.set_zlabel('Service downtime (ms)')
ax.set_zlim(0,8000)
ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x),np.array(y),np.array(z),cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(z),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=9)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color map, in your case `viridis`, will automatically determine which values to use as upper and lower bound.

You can fix these values in `plot_trisurf`'s constructor using `vmin` and `vmax` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots)):

```py
ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x),np.array(y),np.array(z),cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none', vmin=5600, vmax=6100)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(z),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0, vmin=5600, vmax=6100)
```